# How to proxy a TLS socket in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ssl, socks

I am trying to proxy a TLS socket with nodejs. I have tried using the "socks" library, but it does not connect when the endpoint is running TLS.

```
const SocksClient = require("socks").SocksClient;

const options = {
    proxy: {
        host: "localhost",
        port: 9050,
        type: 5
    },

    command: "connect",

    destination: {
        host: "google.com",
        port: 443
    }
}

SocksClient.createConnection(options).then(info => {
    const socket = info.socket;

    socket.write("GET / \r\n\r\n");

    socket.on("error", error => {
        console.error(error);
    });

    socket.on("data", data => {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
});
```

I would expect a TLS socket to be created, but no data is returned when port 443 is used. If I switch the port to 80 it works.

Comment: Do you *have* a SOCKS proxy?

Comment: @user207421Yes, localhost:9050 is running a socks5 proxy. It works for plain http requests, but breaks when a TLS connection is used (https)

Comment: You can't proxy HTTPS unless you MitM all the certificates so that your proxy can act as a SSL terminator. The way to do it without doing that is to use a VPN that tunnels the SSL connections.